# SMTP configuration on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, telnet

Configures SMTP on WordPress but test mail not receiving

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "this option should always be checked yes" - so you sure to check "no"?

Comment: I have also checked using yes opetion..but not resiving mail

Answer (score 0):

To use Wordpress SMTP mail you, as you've done need to configure some details. In this case these details are:

**Mail details**

- **From Email** - the email address you want to send emails from - email@yourdomain.com for example;
- **From Name** - the name that your emails will be received from;
- **SMTP Host** - the hostname for your SMTP server;
- **SMTP Port** - the port your server works on;
- **Encryption** - if you have SSL/TLS encryption available for that hostname, select it here;
- **Authentication** - check if your SMTP server requires authentication;
- **Username** - the username for your SMTP server;
- **Password** - the password for your SMTP server;

[image: Example image]